# Как сделать циклическую связь между контейнерами?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Я поднимаю 2 контейнера mysql. У одного в секции links пишу mysql2, а другого соответ. mysql1. Но докеру не нравится циклическая связь. Как это разрулить?

Comment: Код `yml` покажите. Только **без** паролей и **IP**.

Answer (score 0):

"внутри" одной сети контейнеры видят друг друга

Пример `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysql1:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  mysql2:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

docker-compose создает сеть по-умолчанию, но можно и указать [параметры сети](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) вручную

Запускаем контейнеры

```
docker-compose up
```

Теперь можно проверить (откроем в другом терминале)

```
# перейдем в оболочку первого (запущенного) контейнера 
docker-compose exec mysql1 bash

# и подключимся ко второму контейнеру к mysql серверу
mysql -uroot -proot -hmysql2
```

То же самое работает и наоборот. Docker прописывает соответствиям именам в файле /etc/hosts каждого контейнера.

Если нужно подключаться из разных стеков, то можно создать отдельную сеть или "выставить" порт наружу на IP хоста. Выбор оптимального решения зависит от задачи, которую мы пытаемся решить.

Флаг `--link` устарел и [не рекомендуется к использованию](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/). [Описание для сетевых мостов](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#connect-a-container-to-a-user-defined-bridge) в Docker.